# WinForm closing when 'ok' is selected on messagebox

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a mainform where you can open another window and change options.  One of the options is to copy highlighted text to the clipboard.  if the user doesn't highlight text and clicks btnCopy then I want a message to be shown that no text was highlighted. When the user selects 'ok' I want the messagebox to close but I want the 'options' window to stay open.

Right now when the user clicks 'ok' both the message box and 'options' window closes.  Why is the 'options' window closing?

Here is my code:

```
private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string copySearch = txtSavedSearches.SelectedText;
            if (copySearch == "")
            {
                DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("You did not select anything to copy.  Please select the query to copy.", "Copy search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);                
            }
            else
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(copySearch);
                this.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: this code only, would not make the first windows to close when the messagebox is shown, do other event get triggered ?

Comment: I would take a debugger and step through, there must be some other place Close() is being called.

Comment: Since you are only showing an "OK" message, you don't need to care about the DialogResult of the box, so you can drop the `DialogResult dialog = ` part.

Comment: Did you set the DialogResult property of the btnCopy in the designer?

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete. I tried to reproduce your problem, but with code you provided program behaved like you say so. When text is not selected, it just shows MessageBox, and after clicking OK, MessageBox closes, leaving window open. When text was selected, it is copied to clipboard and everything closes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously set the `DialogResult` property of `btnCopy` to something different than `DialogResult.None`.

If - in a `Form` that is not the application's main window - a `Button` is clicked that has the `DialogResult` property set (to something different than `None`), this click causes the `Form` to close and the calling `ShowDialog()` method to return that `DialogResult`.

Find out where you set that property and remove it.

---

From [MSDN (Button.DialogResult)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the DialogResult for this property is set to anything other than None, and if the parent form was displayed through the ShowDialog method, clicking the button closes the parent form without your having to hook up any events. The form's DialogResult property is then set to the DialogResult of the button when the button is clicked

Comment: Ok, I see now. I take my words back, you are right. It is important, that it is main window, but child window. You deserve upvote.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the 'options' window closing?

The following line will cause the options form to close:

```
                this.Close();
```

You don't need to do anything to close a MessageBox; it goes away by itself when the user clicks OK, and then your code resumes running from the point where `MessageBox.Show` was called. `MessageBox.Show` is a method that returns a value denoting which button the user clicked to get the box to go away (the value varies depending on a) which buttons you chose to show as part of the call to `.Show(...)` and b) which button the user clicked

> Right now when the user clicks 'ok' both the message box and 'options' window closes. Why is the 'options' window closing?

This cannot be, as the message box is shown in the do-if-true part of the IF, and the call to close the options form is called in the ELSE (do if false) part. These two parts cannot run in succession, they must be one or the other. Either your option form closes without a messagebox showing, or a messagebox shows and your form doesn't close

-

Edit:

Renee believes you have set this property:

[image]

on your btnCopy button to be something other than None

And then you have also opened your options form like this:

```
OptionsForm f = new OptionsForm();
f.ShowDialog();
```

These two things combined will conspire to cause your form options to close any time that btnCopy is clicked (unless the clickevent is canceled)

Comment: the messagebox is open only if not in the else closure

Comment: This is wrong, `this.Close()` is in the `else` part.

Comment: The user asked "why is the options window closing" - I answered this question, and also pointed out that the sequence of events posited in the question cannot be the case. Assess whether your downvotes are justified

Comment: So because your post does not solve the issue, you say OP is lying about his observations? I think it's more probable that you're answer is wrong.

Comment: @RenéVogt OP might be lying about his code. To be pricise, he's not telling all the truth. I was not able to reproduce the problem OP showed with information he gave. Moreover, Caius's answer says exactly how .NET WinForms behave. OP is hiding something from us.

Comment: @DominikSzymański well I can reproduce it, by setting `btnCopy.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` for example. So "This cannot be" as Caius states is simply wrong.

Comment: @RenéVogt I see now, but the window that is shown must be children, shown specifically by `.ShowDialog()` method.

Comment: @DominikSzymański that's what my msdn quote says. And I'm sure OP opened his "option" window via `ShowDialog`.

Comment: Hangon, so we now also answer questions that weren't asked? I bow to your crystal ball, Renee..

Comment: @CaiusJard I see your point of course and I also normally don't like to answer unclear questions. But in this special case, my "chrystal ball" is called experience... and if OP doesn't know this little detail, he never would have thought of telling us that property, so only commenting "give more info" wouldn't have helped anyone here. Maybe my answer could have been a simple comment instead...

Comment: I am not trying to hide anything.  I also did a step through and it never comes across this.Close() or any type of close.  I tried to past all the code here but there are too many characters.  How can I attach the code for you to see?  There isn't very much on this page

Comment: I took out the DialogResult port and it still closes the messagebox and the 'Options' window.

Comment: Jacque , Renee is referring to a different DialogResult (the one you set when you opened the options window) - essentially he is saying that because the btnCopy has has a dialog result setting applied, and because the options form is opened which `.ShowDialog` then clicking btnCopy will cause the form to be closed automatically (not by your code). Remove the relevant setting from btnCopy (dialog result) or, don't show the options form as a dialog

Comment: @RenéVogt - you were correct!!!  I did have the DialogResult set to Cancel.  As soon as I changed it to 'none' it worked like expected.

Comment: I edited my answer to include more detail on what Renee believes has happened. I've no comment on why your form is closing outside the code you posted.. YOu should mark Rene's answer as correct if you bellieve it the case